# Defining DDD entities and object values from a dataset of measurements

Tags: machine-learning, domain-driven-design, entity, python-dataclasses, value-objects

I am working on an ML project with a dataset of operating points for a diesel engine. The dataset contains roughly 100 features, ranging from various temperature measurements of fuel/air/exhaust to engine speed and more.

I am looking to apply a DDD approach to my project so I am working on defining a domain model. I am reading up on the matter and talking to domain experts to get a better sense of the domain problem.

That being said, I am having trouble understanding how I can apply the concepts of entities and/or object values to my problem as I feel I might be overengineering here.

This is an example of the table with two operating points:

| OperatingPoint | EngineSpeed | EngineTorque | FuelTemperature | FuelPressure | ExhaustTemperature | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 1000 | 240 | 12 | 500 |  |
| 2 | 300 | 3000 | 350 | 13 | 600 |  |

In spite of the fact that I have a one-to-one relationship between an OperatingPoint and any other measured parameter, in an attempt to better represent the domain and the objects and behaviors therein, I would like to try to divide this table up into dataclasses that I can then store and process individually. I would group measurements based on the domain object they belong to.

I am thinking that the OperatingPoint is an Entity with its specific ID with all other parameters/features of the table being value objects connected to this entity. For example: OperatingPoint (entity), Engine (value object), Fuel (value object), etc.:

```
from base_data import BaseData


class OperatingPoint(BaseData):
    """An entity with its ID."""
    id: int
    engine: Engine


class Engine(BaseData):
    """Value object containing other value objects."""
    operating_point_id: int
    speed: float
    fuel: Fuel
    exhaust_gas: ExhaustGas


class Fuel(BaseData):
    """Value object"""
    operating_point_id: int
    temperature: float
    pressure: float


class ExhaustGas(BaseData):
    """Value object"""
    operating_point_id: int
    temperature: float

...
```

In this case engine (value object) contains two other value objects which are Fuel and ExhaustGas.

Another example: the intake gas (comburent) is a mix of air and EGR gas, so the dataclass IntakeGas would have two properties that represent value objects:

```
from base_data import BaseData
from air import Air
from egr_gas import EGRGas


class IntakeGas(BaseData):
    """Value object containing other value objects."""
    operating_point_id: int
    air: Air
    egr_gas: EGRGas
```

Am I overthinking this problem and creating too much complexion by trying to divide the table up?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern language of domain models may not be a particularly good fit for the problem that you are trying to solve.

---

If I'm interpreting your example correctly, what you have is a big old pile of data samples, or perhaps a continuous stream of data samples.  High cardinality facts[tm], coming to you from system outside of the control of your program.

Your table is, in effect, a cache of messages that weren't lost in transit.

In particular, given a new message, deciding how to add it to that table doesn't seem to require knowing anything about previous entries.

You might need a "parser" (so that you can recognize messages that have been corrupted in transit, rather than polluting your data with garbage); you might need a "filter" (to elide the fields that you don't care about).  But the case for "entities" is not obvious.

It might even be that you have several different (logical) processes, that filter data into different tables, so that your data model has better cohesion (or maybe only better performance characteristics).  That could be fine.

But for the problem where you are just copying input data into your database, the ceremony of "entities" adds unnecessary friction.  So you best be sure that they are delivering value that compensates for that friction, or leave them out.

Comment: The input data is more like a simple static csv data, and I won't be getting new data on a regular basis. I want to somehow get this data into my code but avoid using 3rd party tools like the pandas framework to work with it. Instead I want to define specific data classes and instead of one large dataclass (entity) with 100 properties, I was thinking of splitting the columns into different dataclasses which would be value objects connected to the entity which is the operating point number. Splitting is based on my understanding of the domain and its objects/behaviors. Does that make sense?